# Android Refresh Token without Resend Username and Password

Tags: android, api, token, jwt

I have google and read up articles regard refresh token but still very confusing. What I want to do is, the android application just login once and the token refresh at specific time.

From my understand(Flow):

1. Initial login with username and password. Saved this login credentials on AccountManager.
2. Send login credentials to api
3. Api send token to client
4. Client save token on SharedPreferences
5. Interact the api with token
6. Question is here, if the token expire, do you resend the saved login credentials again to refresh token? OR just sending the expired token and re-generate new token? I'm thinking to do it on jwt. It is necessary to store refresh token on database?

Comment: Generally the API you're interacting with will send you a new token with each request before the old one expires.  You then switch and use that new one.

Comment: @GabeSechan lets say I set it 1 min to expire, after 1 hour, i do a request, it still replace with the new one?

Comment: no, then you may as well just make it last forever.  If the token expires they need to reauthenticate.

Comment: So, resending the login credentials for reauthenticate is the best approach to do it?  Because I search up some article telling the client don't store login credentials, they just storing token. Are they means the token set it to last forever, no refresh token require?

Comment: WHy are you expiring the token?  The only reason to expire the token is for security-  because you want to ensure that the person using the app is still who he says he is.  That means you don't want to save the credentials-  you want him to actually log in.  That means dumping him to a login screen, not saving the password and reauthenticating.  If you aren't going to actually log him out then there's no point in having an expiration time.

Comment: How about if attacker steal your token, do the attacker have access all the time? I'm thinking doing expiring token so it can limit the time for attacker to access all the time.

Comment: Depends on how your server is set to reject/accept tokens on the backend.  If the only way your tokens are rejected is due to expiration, then yes.  You can consider expiring tokens in such a way that when they expire you check to see if the person is still a valid user and issue a new token.  But then the expiration gives no protection against someone logging into a device and not logging out-  the client device is then infinitely authorized unless explicitly rejected.

Comment: @GabeSechan Thanks and appreciate for your help